# Angular6 get all the elements having same Directive name in the Directive itself

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular-directive

I have a Directive named isSelected and I apply it on few elements in different components like

```
<i isSelected class="icon"></i>
<i isSelected class="icon"></i>
<i isSelected class="icon"></i>
<i isSelected class="icon"></i>
```

No how can I get the elements using 'isSelected' Directive in the Directive itself.

```
@Directive({
 selector: '[isSelected]'
})
export class IsSelectedDirective {
   //I need to get all the elements using my directive
}
```

[StackBlitz code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nnhg8h)

In the StackBlitz Code onHover over h1 tag, hovered tag should have 1 opacity rest h1 tags opacity should rise to 0.5.

Please comment if you need any additional information.

Comment: Please explain what you mean to get all elements, what exactly want you to do with them?

Comment: Elements which is using my 'isSelected' Directive in the Directive. In the above code In the directive I should get all four <i> element references.

Comment: with viewChildren you can select all the element with a directive in the component. I supouse you can store in a service (that inject in your directive) the elements of directive too (even I supouse you can refered to the component from de directive using parent) but I think that all you want to do with the directive is better to do in the component

Comment: Ferhad added my use case and also the code sample in Stackblitz.

Comment: Eliseo I cant do it in the component level. I have thought of service based approach but is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this approach after giving it a lot of thought.

```
@Directive({
 selector: '[isSelected]'
})
export class IsSelectedDirective {
  allElements;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.renderer.addClass(this.elem.nativeElement, 'isSelected')
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.allElements = this.document.querySelectorAll('.isSelected');
  }
}
```

The approach is Adding a class while the directive is initialized and later when the view is initialized querying the elements with the class added. It worked for me.

Comment: If it serves your purpose, Great! But try to avoid JavaScript as much as possible and try to implement in an Angular way.

Comment: Thanks emkay I agree with you this is like a temporary solution.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the constructor of your directive you can write something like

```
constructor(private el: ElementRef, private myService: MyService) {
    myService.push(el); 
}
```

Whichever element applies this directive, it's constructor will be called. Create a service which maintains the array of all these elements and with every constructor called push the element to it.
Something on this line

```
@Inject()


export class MyService{
 private elementArray: Array<ElementRef> = [];

 public push(el: ElementRef) {
    this.elementArray.push(el):
 }
 public getElements() {
 return this.elementArray;
 }
}
```

Then inside the directive you can use the same service to get the list of all those elements.

Comment: Thanks, I have thought of same implementation but is there any way we can do it without service?

Comment: Right now I can't think of an alternative. Your elements using directives are spread across different components otherwise we could have done some tweaking to get those element in the component having those elements. Problem is with persisting these elements. If you try to maintain an array in directive class itself, it will be lost as with every directive applied constructor is called afresh and only way to persist is through service as far i could think of. If something comes up I will edit the answer. Or if you can elaborate your use case can think of different approach.

Comment: Added StackBlitz code and provide the use case let me if you still have queries?

Comment: I tried few things, but they couldn't work. For now service based approach will work just fine.

Comment: Thanks emkay, service based approach is like my last approach. but let me know if you find any other approach.